# VB.net WPF Dynamic datagrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a routine that query an access database and then populate the data into a datagrid.

This is what I currently have:

```
sql = "SELECT CCC1, CCC2, CCC3, CCC4, CCC5, CCC6, CCC7, CCC8, CCC9, CCC10, CCC11, CCC12, CCC13, CCC14, CCC15, CCC16, CCC17, CCC18, CCC19, CCC20 FROM CablesT " &
           "WHERE (CableID = " & CableIDTextBox.Text & ")"
da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, Con)

ds.Tables.Clear() 'this is important to clear the table
da.Fill(ds, "DisplaySpecificCable")
WaterfallchartWindow.CableValuesDataGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables("DisplaySpecificCable").DefaultView
```

My XAML looks like this:

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="CableValuesDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="75" Margin="380,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1305" MinColumnWidth="20" CanUserReorderColumns="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="False" ColumnWidth="60" AlternatingRowBackground="Beige" VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameters"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="1mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC1}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="1.5mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC2}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="2.5mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC3}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="4mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC4}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="6mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC5}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="10mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC6}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="16mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC7}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="25mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC8}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="35mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC9}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="50mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC10}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="70mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC11}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="95mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC12}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="120mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC13}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="150mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC14}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="185mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC15}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="240mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC16}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="300mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC17}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="400mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC18}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="500mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC19}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="630mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC20}"></DataGridTextColumn>

                </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
```

This will populate the datagrid row starting from the 2nd column onwards which is what I need But I also would like to:

1. At the "Parameter" column, add static text to the rows. I could not figure out a way to do this.
2. Add a second row to the datagrid via the SQL query of another table. Could not figure this out too.

Help most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first point :
        sql = "SELECT 'Static code of your own' as CCC0, CCC1, CCC2, CCC3, CCC4, CCC5, CCC6, CCC7, CCC8, CCC9, CCC10, CCC11, CCC12, CCC13, CCC14, CCC15, CCC16, CCC17, CCC18, CCC19, CCC20 FROM CablesT " &
           "WHERE (CableID = " & CableIDTextBox.Text & ")"
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, Con)

```
    ds.Tables.Clear() 'this is important to clear the table
    da.Fill(ds, "DisplaySpecificCable")
    WaterfallchartWindow.CableValuesDataGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables("DisplaySpecificCable").DefaultView
```

then

```
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameters"  Binding="{Binding CCC0}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="1mm²" Binding="{Binding CCC1}"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

that's the way i understood your problem. Hope it serves.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i have understood your question : You could try in your SQL staement

Select "static text" AS ParamColumn, CC1, CC2 ...

So you could bind the same way you are doing in the others columns.

Comment: The values CCC1 to CCC20 are integers, or real values in the database. There are no "static text" within the database per se.

Comment: The values CCC1 to CCC20 are integers, or real values in the database. Say this is of value 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on. There are no "static text" within the database per se. What I would like to have on the datagrid is to display the first row, column 1 as "cable capacity" and then column 2 as "1", column 3 as "2" and so on. how do I manually inject the text "cable capacity" ot the first row and first column of the datagrid?

Comment: I have now added in XAML the following:

Comment: I have now added in XAML the following: 
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameters" Binding="{Binding Parameters}"></DataGridTextColumn> and then
sql = "SELECT 'test' AS Parameters, CCC1, CCC2, CCC3, CCC4, CCC5, CCC6, CCC7, CCC8, CCC9, CCC10, CCC11, CCC12, CCC13, CCC14, CCC15, CCC16, CCC17, CCC18, CCC19, CCC20 FROM CablesT " &
                   "WHERE (CableID = " & CableIDTextBox.Text & ")"
but everytime it runs, the code generates an error in the data adapter..

Comment: it seems i didn't understand your question !

Comment: could you please elaborate what is the code required to do the fake field that you referred to?